# JPA Named Query with boolean criteria doesnt work if a null value is passed as boolean parameter

Tags: null, boolean, jpa-2.0

This Works:

```
@NamedQuery(name="all_submissions",query="select s from Submission s where (s.id= :id or s.testCode= :code or s.user.email = :email) and s.readOnce != NULL")
```

#### s.readOnce != NULL

but this doesnt work

```
@NamedQuery(name="search_submissions",query="select s from Submission s where (s.id= :id or s.user.email = :email or s.testCode = :code) and s.readOnce != :readonceflag")
```

#### s.readOnce != :readonceflag

query.setParameter("readonceflag",null);

```
@Column(name="read_once")
public Boolean readOnce;

#sql
read_once  boolean null,
```

So, how do i implement a not null check with boolean properties?

Answer (score 1):

The valid syntax is like in SQL : `where s.readOnce is not null`. You have to treat null as a special case. You can't compare to null with `=`. Nothing is equal to null, not even null, in SQL.

Comment: I think you are talking about native sql. In JPA, "boolFlag != null" works. but "boolFlag != :flag" where the "flag" parameter is set to null doesnt work.

Comment: In my example, s.readOnce refers to whether the message s is `read(readOnce=true)` or `unread(readOnce=false)`. Now with s.readOnce != :readFlag, I can set readFlag to true if I have to search only for unread messages or set readFlag to null if I have to search for both read as well as unread messages. The named query remains the same.